# Can we configure TCP Level Load balance of ActiveMQ server?

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, activemq-classic, load-balancing

I am using Apache Camel with `ActiveMQ` for Routing Message to Queue. To avail high availability we can configure cluster of MQ server in case of system gets fail. 
ActiveMQ  also provide `failover` features. now i wanted to load balance two set of MQ server to single IP:port at TCP level. Can Failover feature would able to load balance two MQ servers ?

e.g.
One IP is load balanced.

```
192.168.0.1:61616 --> 192.168.1.1:61616,192.168.1.2:61616
```

Answer (score 2):

Load balancing can be done through the "Network of Broker" feature of ActiveMQ, see http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html.

Answer (score 1):

Client failover uri is for recovery, not load balancing. Load balancing messaging clients ends up being a complicated mess (since you can't predict message size).

A good approach is to use the failover:(tcp://...)?randomize=false and partition your producer traffic into groups by changing the order of the brokers in the uri.

Group1 producers: 192.168.1.1:61616,192.168.1.2:61616
Group2 producers: 192.168.1.2:61616,192.168.1.1:61616